# run outside application and track whether it's finished

Tags: c#

I have a Form that allows users to setup a backup solution. I would like the option to allow then to "force a backup now" when clicking a button. My question is, the app that currently controls the function is a console app, that doesn't show the console window. Is there a way for me to start the app and track it's status, like give a working screen and when it's done use messagebox to relay the completed status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe do something with [Process.WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This is from [this msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page on Standard error.

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the error stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "BackupProgram.exe";
p.Start();
//you could read the standard error from the backup program
//incase something went wrong.. 
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
//warning the thread will BLOCK on this method. 
p.WaitForExit();
```

**Notes:**

If you have a windows forms application then you need to handle the blocking correctly. If you call `WaitForExit()` on your main thread your application is going to hang up.

I don't think you can just show a status directly. Unless you code your backup program to communicate with your main program.

So you could use a background worker or some async programming to implement the run and wait and then you could show a indeterminate progress status. ([progressBar1.Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style.aspx) = [ProgressBarStyle.Marquee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle.aspx))

Comment: +1ed as this is the correct way to do this... there is a second way by using `while(!p.HasExited)`

Answer (score 0):

Just put your message box warn into your ConsoleApplication, if that works for you. That means, your console application runs in background without console being shown to user. When the application reaches the end, it calls `MessageBox.Show("I'm done.")` and the message is shown to user.